# python dictionary with two running totals

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data which consists of a series of categories, each with two amounts. For example, `{'cat':'red', 'a':1, 'b':2}, {'cat':'red', 'a':3, 'b':3}, {'cat':'blue', 'a':1, 'b':3}`

I want to keep a running total of the two amounts, by category. Result would be `{'cat':'red', 'a':4, 'b':5}, {'cat':'blue', 'a':1, 'b':3}`

Is there a more pythonic method than:

```
totals = {}
for item in data:
    if item['cat'] in totals:
        totals[item['cat']]['a'] += item['a']
        totals[item['cat']]['b'] += item['b']
    else:
        totals[item['cat']] = {'a':item['a'], 'b':item['b']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure should really be moved to a dictionary, keyed on the `cat` value. Use [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to keep track of the values and make summing easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

totals = defaultdict(Counter)

for item in data:
    cat = item.pop('cat')
    totals[cat] += Counter(item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> data = {'cat':'red', 'a':1, 'b':2}, {'cat':'red', 'a':3, 'b':3}, {'cat':'blue', 'a':1, 'b':3}
>>> totals = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for item in data:
...     cat = item.pop('cat')
...     totals[cat] += Counter(item)
... 
>>> totals
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'blue': Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 1}), 'red': Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4})})
>>> totals['blue']
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 1})
>>> totals['red']
Counter({'b': 5, 'a': 4})
```

If you still require a sequence of dictionaries in the same format, you can then turn the above dictionary of counters back into 'plain' dictionaries again:

```
output = []
for cat, counts in totals.iteritems():
    item = {'cat': cat}
    item.update(counts)
    output.append(item)
```

resulting in:

```
>>> output
[{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'cat': 'blue'}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'cat': 'red'}]
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd thought of using defaultdict or Counter, but not defaultdict(Counter).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [dict.setdefault](http://python.net/~mwh/hacks/setdefault.html) and [collections.counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).
Possible solution using setdefault:

```
totals = {}
for item in data:
    d = totals.setdefault(item['cat'],  {'a':0, 'b':0})
    d['a'] += item['a']
    d['b'] += item['b']
```

with result `total = {'blue': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, 'red': {'a': 4, 'b': 5}}`. Note that this does not have the `'cat'` entries like in your expected answer. Instead, the colors are used directly as the key for the resulting dictionary.

See Martijn's answer for an example using `Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

I would collect your data into a temporary composite data structure based on a combination of the [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) classes. The keys of this data structure would be the cat's color and associated with each will be a `Counter`to hold the totals for each color cat. Making it a`defaultdict`means not having to worry about whether it's first time the color has been encountered and or not.

This will perform the summing of values needed as it is created and is fairly easy to turn into the output sequence you want afterwards:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

data = ({'cat':'red', 'a':1, 'b':2},
        {'cat':'red', 'a':3, 'b':3},
        {'cat':'blue', 'a':1, 'b':3})

cat_totals = defaultdict(Counter)  # hybrid data structure
for entry in data:
    cat_totals[entry['cat']].update({k:v for k,v in entry.iteritems() 
                                            if k != 'cat'})

results = tuple(dict([('cat', color)] + cat_totals[color].items())
            for color in cat_totals)

print results # ({'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'cat': 'blue'}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'cat': 'red'})
```